# Optic api, existsJoin by two or more columns causes a decrease in performance

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

For such input data, I want to obtain a result in which I will have only those values that for the same id1 and id2 have the value of Reported and Primary.

```
var items = [
    {
      "id1": 241,
      "id2": 716,
      "type": "Primary"
    },
    {
      "id1": 241,
      "id2": 716,
      "type": "Reported"
    },
    {
      "id1": 477,
      "id2": 850,
      "type": "Reported"
    },
    {
      "id1": 563,
      "id2": 340,
      "type": "Primary"
    },
    {
      "id1": 649,
      "id2": 322,
      "type": "Reported"
    }];
```

I try to use exists join like below:

```
const op = require('/MarkLogic/optic');

var reportedItems = op.fromLiterals(items)
    .where(op.in(op.col('type'), 'Reported'))
    .select(['id1', 'id2'], 'reported');

var primaryItems = op.fromLiterals(items)
    .where(op.in(op.col('type'), 'Primary'))
    .select(['id1', 'id2'], 'primary')

primaryItems
    .existsJoin(reportedItems, [
        op.on(op.viewCol('primary', 'id1'),
            op.viewCol('reported', 'id1')),
        op.on(op.viewCol('primary', 'id2'),
            op.viewCol('reported', 'id2'))
    ])
    .select("id1")
    .result()
    .toArray()
```

However, when the number of items in the input data exceeds 5000, the execution time exceeds 2 seconds. If, however, I perform a join only on one property (e.g. id1), the result will almost immediately appear (for 5k objects 0.3s).

Why is it so slow, can I improve it in some way or use another method to obtain the same result?

Comment: This is an interesting one. Sometimes I have had luck in performance by adding the second condition not as a second "on", but using the third param. However, that does not seem to be the root of the problem.

Upon analysis and profiling, the issue does not seem to be solely the second op.on, but the actual last call to toArray(). In my test, I created 15000 Primary, 500 Reported with an overlap of 1 record.

With ``toArray()`` _removed_, 0.56 seconds

With ``toArray()`` in place, 5.2 seconds - and the profile tab shows 98% of time spent in `toArray()`.

Comment: Yes, but if you perform the query without one of the join conditions (ON) like without (        op.on(op.viewCol('primary', 'id1'),  op.viewCol('reported', 'id1'))), the toArray() method will not negatively impact the query's performance even though it will have more elements to map.

Comment: Generally, an existsJoin works much slower on TDE views regardless of the toArray() method used. Currently, I'm trying to use inner join in order to limit the results, because exists join is much slower.

Answer (score 1):

I expect this should give the same result, and in my testing it seems to be much faster:

```
'use strict';

const op = require('/MarkLogic/optic');

var reportedItems = op.fromView('test', 'exists')
    .where(op.in(op.col('type'), 'Reported'))
    .select(['id1', 'id2'], 'reported')
    .whereDistinct();

var primaryItems = op.fromView('test', 'exists')
    .where(op.in(op.col('type'), 'Primary'))
    .select(['id1', 'id2'], 'primary')
    .whereDistinct()

primaryItems
  .joinInner(reportedItems, [
    op.on(op.viewCol('primary', 'id1'),
      op.viewCol('reported', 'id1'))
  ],
    op.eq(op.viewCol('primary', 'id2'),
      op.viewCol('reported', 'id2'))
  )
  .select(op.viewCol('primary', 'id1'), '')
  .result()
```

What I think is happening in the original query is that the `existsJoin` is performing a cross product join of `primary` and `reported`, and using that result to filter `primary`.  Because the cross product is so large, the filter takes a long time to execute.

It might be possible to omit `whereDistinct` if you know you don't have any duplicate rows - my data was randomly generated for testing so I had to use it.